# Query subdocuments MongoDB Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection of objects which have a sub dictionary which contains data for a given institution, identified by the `provider_id`.

How can I query a collection, `products` and return only produce which contain a given provider id?

```
  "natl_total_cost": 1.27478784E9,
  "natl_average": 8338.487,
  "natl_report_count": 152880,
  "name": "Wax",
  "provider_cost_dict": {
     "340008": {
        "report_count": 181,
        "total_cost": 1335465,
        "average_cost": 7378.26
     },
     "340001": {
        "report_count": 643,
        "total_cost": 5026724,
        "average_cost": 7817.6113
     },
...
```

How could I query all of the products so that it only returns products which contain a given provider id in their `provider_cost_dict`?

Comment: can you post your schema??  what is `340008` in the above document?

Comment: The `340008` is a provider id, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator like so

```
db.getCollection('yourColl').find({"provider_cost_dict.340008": { $exists: true }})
```